# Query regarding a theorem in Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial

Please refer to Theorem $8$ in the attached picture.
[image]

I do not understand the significance of the condition $(n+1)!+k>k$. Is it not always true since the inequation implies $(n+1)!>0$ which is always true. Also why are the numbers taken as $(n+1)!+k$ and not $n!+k$. Why does $k$ start from $2$ and not from $1$? Also what is the meaning of the line: "Thus, there are arbitrarily large gaps in the sequence of primes."? How are the gaps "arbitrarily large"?

Comment: Knowing that $(n+1)!+k$ is divisible by $k$ doesn't show $(n+1)!+k$ is prime, unless we also know that $k\geq 2$ and $(n+1)!+k>k.$ So you it is necessary to mention this in the proof.

Comment: Arbitrarily is an adverb, so it applies to the word "large," not "gap." This just means that the distance between consecutive primes has no upper bound. It is a common English usage of "arbitrarily" in math.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, but $(n+1)!+k>k$ is always true. So why mention it as a condition?

Comment: It's not a "condition," it is an observation that is necessary to assert that $(n+1)!+k$ is not prime. The fact that it is obviously true doesn't mean you don't need to mention it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, Alright. But how does this all imply that "there are arbitrarily large gaps in the sequence of primes."? Given any positive integer $n$, the consecutive sequence of composite numbers is of length $n$. So we know the size of the gap. How is it arbitrarily large?

Comment: Because $n$ can be chosen to be arbitrarily large...

Answer (score 2):

**Stating the obvious**

The only reason the proof mentions that $(N+1)!+k>k$ is that it is not enough to know that:

> 1. $k\geq 2$
> 2. $k$ divides $D$.

to conclude that $D$ is composite. Specifically, if $k$ is prime, and $k=D$, then (1) and (2) are true, but $D$ is not composite.

If we also know also that $D>k,$ **then** we can conclude that $D$ is composite.

So, even though it is trivially true that $(N+1)!+k>k,$ we need to mention it in proving that $(N+1)!+k$ is composite.

---

**Prime gaps**

If $2=p_1<p_2<p_3<\cdots<p_n<\cdots$ are all the primes, then a prime gap is the difference between two consecutive primes $p_{n+1}-p_n.$ If $p_{n+1}-p_n=N+1$ then $p_{n}+1,p_{n}+2,\dots,p_{n}+N$ are $N$ consecutive composite numbers.

On the other hand, assume  $k,k+1,\dots,k+N-1$ are $N$ consecutive composite numbers.

We can let $p=p_n$ be the largest prime such that $p\leq k-1.$

Now, it is not possible that $p_{n+1}\leq k-1,$ or we'd contradict that $p_n$ is the largest prime $\leq k-1.$ So $p_{n+1}\geq k.$ But $k,k+1,\dots,k+N-1$ are not prime, so $p_{n+1}\geq k+N.$

Then

$$p_{n+1}-p_n \geq (k+N)-(k-1)=N+1.$$

So there exists $N$ consecutive composite numbers if and only if there is a prime gap of size at least $N+1.$

The quoted proof proves that we can find $N$ consecutive composite numbers for any $N,$ namely with $k=(N+1)!+2.$ so we can make prime gaps of size at least $N+1$ for any $N,$ which is what we mean by saying that the prime gaps can be arbitrarily large.

Probably an easier way to phrase:

> There are arbitrarily large prime gaps.

is to say

> The prime gap function $f(n)=p_{n+1}-p_n$ is not bounded above.

Answer (score 0):

a few answers:

- $k$ starts at 2, because $y!+1$ can be prime examples are $y=2,3$, and $k=1$ being proved to cause divisibility by 1 shows nothing about it potentially being composite.
- $n+1$ is used to save cases like $n=4$ from the results of $k>1$
- The gaps get as large as you want, based on $n$, because $n+1$ grows with $n$. Otherwise we wouldn't need to choose or be given, any n in the positive integers.

Comment: I did not understand the second point. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Because n=4;n!+1=25 is composite. But,because we eliminated k=1, we only have 26,27,28 only 3 numbers composite that the formula now would say is 4, so we need to move to another value of $y$, $y=n+1$ is available and works.

Comment: Why have you chosen $4$? Isn't it valid for every positive integral value for $n$?

Comment: because 4 is a small case where elimating $k=1$ wrecks the n! will work thought.